# Record for player hitting the woodwork most number of times in a season in top European leagues?

Tags: football, records, english-premier-league, la-liga, bundesliga

[Robin van Persie hitting the woodwork 10 times in a Premier League 2011/12](http://eplindex.com/15004/robin-van-persie-the-best-of-the-best-opta-stats.html) is the biggest one that I have found so far for Premier League. Is this the record for Premier League, and what is the record for other European Leagues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La Liga:**

In 2017/18 season, Lionel Messi hit the woodwork [**18** times](https://www.fcbarcelona.com/football/first-team/news/2017-2018/denied-by-the-woodwork-fcbarcelona), which according to [Opta](https://twitter.com/OptaJose/status/964923151607107584/photo/1), is the most in La Liga season since 2003/2004.

**Premier League:**

In 2011/12 season, Robin van Persie hit the woodwork [**10** times](https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/hit_woodwork), which according to [premierleague.com](https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/hit_woodwork), is the most in a Premier League season since 2006/2007.

---

**Bundesliga:**

In 2017/18 season, Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang hit the woodwork [**5** times](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/stats/bundesliga/current-season/all-matchdays/player-stats/shots-at-goal-wood-work) *(I couldn't find anyone else with more and this is most probably not a record).*

Comment: I couldn't find any records for Serie A or Ligue 1, but will keep an eye on stats.